# Explain the role of the numerator and denominator of a rational exponent such as $\left(\frac{27x^3}{8y^9}\right)^{-\frac{5}{3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I understand how to solve this problem,
(8y^9 / 27x^3)^5/3
((2y^3)^5 / (3x)^5
(2y^3)^5 / (3x)^5
***(32y^15) / (243x^5)***
but i am confused as to what the direct role of the numerator and denominator is of rational exponents such as this one. Is the role of the numerator the power of the term in parenthesis, and the denominator is the value of the root of the term in parenthesis? I understand that if the outer exponent is negative then when you simplify the total expression the items that were in the numerator will be in the denominator and the items that were in the denominator will be in the numerator.

Comment: Do you know how to define $b^{\frac{m}{n}}$?

Comment: What do you mean "role"?

Comment: yes i know how to define b m/n. What i mean by role is its purpose in a rational exponent like the example i gave

Comment: What do you mean "you know the answer"?  What is the question you know the answer to, and what is the answer?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying that properly. I know that the answer to (27x^3/8y^9)^-5/3 is (32y^15) / (243x^5), is the role of the numerator to be the power of the term in parenthesis and the denominator is the value of the root of the term in the parenthesis? @JoelReyesNoche

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so here is a little guidance.

When you first learn exponentiation, you learn that stacked exponents *multiply*. In other words, $(2^2)^3=2^{2\times3}=2^6$. You should be able to convince yourself that's true just by writing it out:
$$
(2^2)^3 = (2\times 2)^3= (2\times 2)\times(2\times 2)\times(2\times 2)=2^6
$$

Now, we want to figure out what $2^{\frac{1}{2}}$ should mean. If we obey the same rule, we know that we should have
$$
(2^{\frac{1}{2}})^2=2^{2\times\frac{1}{2}}=2^1=2$$

Thus, when we write $2^{\frac{1}{2}}$, we mean *some number which squares to 2*. Thus, $2^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is just the square root of 2, $\sqrt{2}$.

If you use similar logic, you'll see that $2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ should *cube* to 2, and thus $2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is the third root of 2; similarly, $2^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is the nth root of 2, $\sqrt[n]{2}$.

Now, we're ready to deal with general fractions!

Using the multiplication rule, we can write $2^{\frac{a}{b}}$ as $(2^{a})^{\frac{1}{b}}$, since $a\times\frac{1}{b}=\frac{a}{b}$. Now you should know what to do! First, you raise 2 to the power of $a$. Second, you take your result and find the bth root. And that's the answer!

You can also do it the other way around. You can write $2^{\frac{a}{b}}=(2^{\frac{1}{b}})^a$. This tells you to first take the bth root of 2, then raise the result to the power of $a$. Both methods will give the same answer.

The only remaining thing that might give you trouble is, what if your fraction is negative? Well, if we have a negative fraction $-\frac{a}{b}$, we can write it as $\frac{-a}{b}$, and just use all the rules I gave you with $a$ replaced by $-a$. So, you just need to know how to raise something to a NEGATIVE integer. Let's see how to do that:

One other thing you should remember about exponentiation is that we have $2^a\times 2^b = 2^{a+b}$. For positive integers, this is pretty easy to prove just by writing it out:
$$
2^2\times2^3=(2\times 2)\times(2\times 2\times 2)=2^5
$$
Now we need to figure out what $2^{-a}$ should mean. Using the rule above, we have
$$
2^a\times 2^{-a} = 2^{a+(-a)}=2^0=1
$$
Using basic algebra, we can see that this means

$$
2^{-a}=\frac{1}{2^a}
$$

Now, you should be able to exponentiate anything! And remember, we get the rules by taking basic properties of *positive integer exponents*, and trying to make them hold for negative integers and fractions.

Comment: As a side note, if this all makes sense to you, you should think about how one might define taking a number to an *irrational power*.

Comment: Thank you, i understand your answer but i am still a little confused. I don't understand the direct role of the numerator and denominator in a rational exponent like (27x^3/8y^9)^-5/3, is it asking the role of the 5/3? I understand what the role of the negative in the exponent is, just not the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: The numerator is the power you raise to, the denominator is the root to take. So if you take something to the 5/3 power, you multiply it by itself five times, then take the third root.

Answer (score 1):

If the fraction inside the parentheses has only positive exponents in both numerator and denominator, then

- if the outer exponent is negative then when you simplify the total expression the items that were in the numerator will be in the denominator and the items that were in the denominator will be in the numerator.
- if the outer exponent is positive then the items in the numerator or denominator will stay where they are.

Is this simple and comprehensive enough?

Comment: Yes- thank you!